# How to factor out logging?

Tags: logging, refactoring

Is there a good way to factor out logging from a class?

The only thing I'm aware of is if logging happens at the beginning/end of `methodA` you can factor the logging in an intermediare method `methodIntermediate` and then call `methodA` from `methodIntermediate`. On a class level you could use a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and have all the logging in the decorator. But that wouldn't help with the logging that is in the middle of the method.

I just think it is ugly to have a class with lots of logging statements interspersed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way around recording *information* about something which happens, be it good or bad, inside a method when it actually happens.  But you need not log then and there.  One alternative which I like is to simply record a message, and make the log later on.

```
public class LogsAreBad {
    private String msg = "";
    // helper method which is never called directly
    private void helper() {
        boolean result = doSomething();
        if (!result) {
            msg += "something went wrong in helper();";
        }
    }

    private void resetLog() {
        msg = "";
    }

    public int method() {
        resetLog();
        helper();
        msg += "Someone accessed method()";
        logger.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Logging writes output to a black box.  This does the same in effect.  How is this interestingly different?

Comment: @IraBaxter I gave the caviat that I saw no way to avoid recording information about the flow of code when that actually code is happening.  My answer only frees the need to use an actual logger throughout a class.  I can remove this answer if it morally offends you.

Comment: It doesn't offend me.  Just want readers to be clear on what it says. With these comments, I'm fine with it.